# onclick with twig and javascript

Tags: javascript, twig

how can i display the clicked Image in my container? It displays me only the code from clicked image.

1. There is the image and my JavaScript function.

   ```
   <div class="col-xs-2">
       {# @var asset \Pimcore\Model\Asset #}
       {% if articleAC.getElement.imageProduct != null %}
         <img src="{{ articleAC.getElement.imageProduct.getThumbnail('contentSmal').getHTML() }}" onclick="myFunction();" alt="newImage">

         {# Js presents the klicked image #}
          <script type="text/javascript">
          document.getElementById("mainImage").onclick = function () {
          myFunction();
          };

          function myFunction() {
          document.getElementById("mainImage").innerHTML = "src="{{ articleAC.getElement.imageProduct.getThumbnail('contentSmal').getHTML() }}"";
           }
           </script>
           {% endif %}
                   </div>
   ```
2. With a click of the image above, it should be displayed in my :

`<div id="mainImage" class="product-image-gallary">
<img class="img-rounded" src="" alt="newImage">`

If I click the Image it displays me only the img-tag with the twig code!
Why?

Comment: What returns `getHtml()` ?